# mongodb do i need to put my config servers on separate servers?

Tags: mongodb

i assume yes since if an instance goes down all 3 go down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and also the routing protocol is [optimized for 3 machines](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Configuring+Sharding#ConfiguringSharding-ConfigServers).